# Trying to make a difference between two dates, with days, hours and minutes

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I try to make a difference between two dates, but displaying the days and hours. So I found a good idea on this website : https://sharepointonline.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/date-time-duration-using-calculated-field-column/

I have adapted my code with my start time column *Debut Diag* and my end time column *Fin Diag* :

```
=DATEDIF([Debut Diag],[Fin Diag]-(MOD([Debut Diag],1)>MOD([Fin Diag],1)),"d")&" Day(s) "&TEXT(MOD([Fin Diag]-[Debut Diag],1),"hh"" Hour(s) ""mm"" Min(s)""")
```

Tried with h instead of hh too

But I get an error SharePoint, that explains nothing or gives no idea of the problem. Maybe I have a syntax error, or the way can't work. Can you tell me what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the error you are receiving, if you are using different regional settings than English in your site, try to replace all the commas (`,`) to semicolons (`;`).

You could make a easier calculation to. This one returns the number of days, hours and minutes between the 2 dates.

```
=TEXT([Fin Diag]-[Debut Diag];"d:h:mm")
```

**Update**

Tried out your calculation in my environment, but i replaced the commas and it worked perfectly.

[image]

Comment: yeah thx guy it was that! Just replaced the commas by semi-column and worked!! Thanks!